Pop-up message or sound notification in QField app?
I would like to add a notification to our QField app. We have a route tracking layer (MultiLine with a real-time distance column) and a measurement (Point) layer. While route tracking, we need to take measurements every 5 kilometers. It would be very helpful to have some kind of alert that lets us know that we have travelled 5 kilometers and therefore it is time to fill in the measurement form.
Are sound notifications or pop-up messages possible in the QField app?
Perhaps with a QML or HTML widget?
I have never worked with those before, so this is completely new to me. I do have basic knowledge of HTML.
Could someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?
